# How can I find my chipset, and tell if my adapter is ieee80211 or mac80211

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.10, realtek, aircrack-ng

I have a Realtek RTL8187SE B/G adapter on Ubuntu 14.10. I was wondering if there was a command that lets me find my chipset because I use "airmon-ng start wlan0", and it says that the Chipset is unknown. And I was also wondering if there was a command that lets me find out if my network adapter was either ieee80211 or mac80211.

Comment: The commands lspci and lsusb should give some useful information. It might not tell you, but it could.